# APA: how to cite a translation of an old work in a compilation that has been reissued

Tags: translation, apa

This might seem to be a strange question, but I can't seem to get my head around it.

- I am trying to cite from Anselm's "On Truth", which is part of a compilation.
- I have read it in Oxford World Classics' *Anselm of Canterbury: The Major Works*.
- "On Truth" was translated from Latin into English by Ralph McInery, but other parts of the volume were translated by others.
- On top of that, this version of *Anselm of Canterbury: The Major Works* is a reissued edition. The original was published in 1998.
- The original "On Truth" (*De veritate* in Latin) was published around 1080.

What I thought that could be a solution is the following (in a reference list):

```
Anselm. (2008). On Truth (R. McInery, Trans.). In B. Davies & G. Evans
    (Eds.), *Anselm of Canterbury: The Major Works* (pp. 151-174). USA:
    Oxford University Press. (Reissue edition. Original edition 1998.
    Original work published around 1080).
```

> ```
> *this means that the text contained within is in italics*
> ```

I do not know

1. whether this is correct;
2. how I would cite this source in a text.

But because there are so many factors to keep in mind, it is hard to know whether this is completely correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. <s>USA</s> New York: Oxford University Press
2. <s>Reissue edition. Original edition 1998.</s>

Why delete that? No one cares if that book is an unchanged reissue. You only tell the reader if the book you quote from is a different *editon* (e.g. 2nd ed.), because that means that there have been changes to the text, and therefore it is important to identify the correct edition. In your case you have an unchanged reissue, and if someone wanting to look at your source text picked up the first edtion from 1998 he would find the same text on the same pages. [Google Books shows you that the text is on the same page in the 1998 printing](http://books.google.de/books?id=hXXBBuJ2MocC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Anselm%20of%20Canterbury%3a%20The%20Major%20Works%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=kfkAU-alOonTsgaj7oBA&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=snippet&q=%22on%20truth%22%20%22preface%22&f=false).

What you get is:

> Anselm. (2008). On Truth (R. McInery, Trans.). In B. Davies & G. Evans (Eds.), *Anselm of Canterbury: The Major Works* (pp. 151-174). New York: Oxford University Press. (Original work published around 1080).

If you really and truly need this quotation to be perfect, ask on the APA style blog: http://blog.apastyle.org/ – they helped me with some complicated quote from a 19th century French text.

Note that in text you should use the following citation:

> (Anselm, 1080/2008)

*For an official example see no. 21 on page 203f. of the 2009 6th editon of the APA Publication Manual.*

---

Apart from a certain formatting style, the basic APA rule is to **include everything necessary to clearly identify a source**. You don't have to go beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. but I would omit the words Reissue edition, change Origional edition to First edition and add a note about translation so it would read something like "(First edition 1998. Translated by Ralph McInery 19XX.
    Original Latin published around 1080)"